# How to convert string variable into boolean in Matlab?

Tags: string, matlab, boolean, type-conversion

I have a matlab script and one of the variables is:

```
a = 'false' % my string
```

my goal is to convert such variable into a boolean variable:

```
a = false % my goal
```

is there a matlab function that allows me to convert the string into a boolean value?

```
a = string2boolean('false') % I would like to have something like this
```

If there are no functions that allow to do that what could be another possible solution?

Comment: In Matlab it is called `logical`. Is it always 'true' or 'false'? Why not just `strcmpi(a,'true')`?

Comment: use `~strcmp(a, 'false')`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write one yourself, it's rather simple

```
function [output]=string2boolean(string)
   if strcmp(string,'false')
     output = false;
   else
     output = true;
   end
end
```

Additionally you can altogether skip the function and simply

```
a = strcmp(a,'true');
```

Comment: Or, if OP want's it a bit simpler: `string2boolean = @(s) ~strcmpi(s, 'false');`

Comment: @StewieGriffin That's shorter, but not simpler. Especially to a beginner the code above is more readable.

Answer (score 5):

You can misuse `strcmpi` for this, i.e

```
 a = strcmpi(a, 'true');
```

This is a case-insensitive string comparison, so `true`, `True` and `TRUE` are all converted to the logical true. All other strings will be automatically converted to false.

Comment: @Federico: And `a = ~strcmpi(a, 'false')`. Gives `a = false` if `a = 'false'`.

Comment: @StewieGriffin The line that I wrote also gives `a = false` if `a='false'`, no reason to write it that superfluous.

Comment: So does `'abc'` or `[1 2 3]`. It is possible that there are other options than `'true'` and `'false'`, since OP hasn't answered the question you asked in the comments. PS! I didn't mean OP should have _both_ `'true'` and `'false'`. But it's the `'false'` part that's "guaranteed" to answer OP's question. The `'true'` version might be wrong (but probably isn't).

Comment: That is weird. If you make a function that converts something to a boolean, it should give either `true` or `false`. But Matlab is not typesafe, so you could indeed return anything. That will however be unexpected behavior for future users of your function.

Comment: I agree, but there are many strange ways to do things. Suppose OP has: `if x == 0; y = [1, 2, 3]; else y = 'false'; end`. Also, I agree, it should convert it to `true` or `false`, but it's possible that everything that's **not** false is true, and not the other way around.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Well, in that case I give up. If people do that kind of stuff they are lost. You can't teach a pig to speak. :)

Comment: Well, for some reason OP get's `'false'` as a string. There's already something fishy going on. :) PS! I think your answer is good, and I didn't mean for you to edit it in any way. But it's a possibility that OP didn't know about the `~` operator, that's why I commented. Everybody starts somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

`str2num` works (tested with Matlab R2018a)

```
str2num( '1' ) %yields double(1)
str2num( '0' ) %yields double(0)
str2num( 'true' ) %yields logical(1)
str2num( 'false' ) %yields logical(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a method/function as follows:

```
function boolValue = string2boolean(stringValue)

    boolValue = ''
    if strcmpi(string,'false')
        boolValue = false
    end

    if strcmpi(string,'true')
        boolValue = true
    end
```

Comment: Did you even test your function? This cannot work, you are doing an assignment in the `if`-statement.

Comment: @Bernhard Thanks for pointing out, actually I have provided this just by logical thinking and I haven't run in MATLAB, so after assignment operator correction, code will run correctly.

Comment: Comparison operator does not work like that in Matlab. Consider removing your answer, it does not make sense.

Comment: It would make sense if you changed `==` to `strcmp`, but then it will be a plain copy of the other answer. I agree with @Bernhard here.

Comment: I am really surprised that a plain wrong answer attracts more upvotes than two correct answers.

Comment: @StewieGriffin @Bernhard instead of adding `strcmp` it should be `strcmpi` so that it ignore any differences in letter case. I have answered initially this question to achieve the question's requirements logically not by running code.

Comment: @krishnaPrasad, well, that depends on what OP wants... No need to support mixed case words if only lower case words are given. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ismember`:

```
str = "true";   % 'true' also works
ismember(lower(str), {'true','1'})    % returns 1
```

This allows alternative true values than supported natively by Matlab's `logical`:

```
str = 'yes';
ismember(lower(str), {'true','1','yes','enable'})  % returns 1
```

[image]